# How to send double quotes inside JSON curl request

Tags: json, linux, shell, curl

I want to send this string inside a CURL request from shell script :

```
"google-site-verification=O_Kd7lqvCvpBz7fzEeUKGVKBmsAsfJgaJuh3PZRnrsk"
```

To do that I'm using this script :

```
OVH_HTTP_METHOD="POST"
OVH_HTTP_QUERY="$OVH_API_URL/$OVH_API_END_POINT_DOMAIN_ZONE_DNS/domain.com/$OVH_API_END_POINT_DOMAIN_ZONE_DNS_RECORD"
OVH_FIELD_TYPE="TXT"
OVH_SUB_DOMAIN=""
OVH_TARGET=""google-site-verification=O_Kd7lqvCvpBz7fzEeUKGVKBmsAsfJgaJuh3PZRnrsk""
OVH_HTTP_BODY="{\"fieldType\":\"$OVH_FIELD_TYPE\",\"subDomain\":\"$OVH_SUB_DOMAIN\",\"target\":\"$OVH_TARGET\"}"

curl -X $OVH_HTTP_METHOD \
    $OVH_HTTP_QUERY \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "X-Ovh-Application: $OVH_API_APPLICATION_KEY" \
    -H "X-Ovh-Timestamp: $OVH_TIME" \
    -H "X-Ovh-Signature: $OVH_SIG" \
    -H "X-Ovh-Consumer: $OVH_API_CONSUMER_KEY" \
    --data "$OVH_HTTP_BODY"
```

But I get systematically this error message :

```
{"message":"Invalid JSON received","httpCode":"400 Bad Request","errorCode":"INVALID_JSON"}
```

UPDATE with curl -v :

[image]

Do you have any idea to solve that?

Thanks
L.

Comment: OVH_TARGET="\"google-site-verification=O_Kd7lqvCvpBz7fzEeUKGVKBmsAsfJgaJuh3PZRnrsk\""

Comment: If you don't rely on variable substitution inside the string you can use single quotes for a literal string: `'"google-site-verification=XXXXXX"'`. Also make sure you don't post sensitive information.

Comment: @ Raman Sailopal : I have tried and same error

Comment: @Jorge Bellon : same problem (these infos are fake no problem)

Comment: OK. Would you mind posting the output of that curl command with `-v` (verbose) option turned on? That should show the body of the request in order to verify what the problem with the JSON validation is.

Comment: @Jorge Bellon : ok done, I have added a picture on post 1 because too much, I cannot save the message.

Comment: Since unfortunately the output of curl didn't help much, you can see what the server is receiving at the other end by using netcat in listen mode. You change the query url to `localhost:XXX`, run in another shell `nc -l XXX` and then your curl command again. I did that and passed the last line (the body of the request) into a JSON parser (`jq`) and didn't see any JSON parsing errors, so the problem you are getting might be a semantic one, not a syntax one. I ran `nc -l 65432 | tail -n1  | jq .`

Comment: The JSON received at the server end was:
`{
  "fieldType": "TXT",
  "subDomain": "",
  "target": "google-site-verification=O_Kd7lqvCvpBz7fzEeUKGVKBmsAsfJgaJuh3PZRnrsk"
}`

Comment: the problem is we have that : "target":""google-site-verification=O_Kd7lqvCvpBz7fzEeUKGVKBmsAsfJgaJuh3PZRnrsk"" so how to escape the double quote before and after google-site string?

Comment: because when I look DNS zone, the double quote before and after google-site string is not added and I need it..see here : https://prnt.sc/wlymy0

Comment: any idea .... :-/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution found below : variable has to be escaped like this :

```
OVH_TARGET="\\\"google-site-verification=O_Kd7lqvCvpBz7fzEeUKGVKBmsAsfJgaJuh3PZRnrsk\\\""
```